# typesafe stack scala error

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I am using http://typesafe.com/stack/ for the first time, and I created simple akka project. My scala version is 2.9.2 I get the following error.

```
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/hrishikeshparanjape/git-public/web-service/target/scala-2.9.2/classes...
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.9.2. Compiling...
sbt appears to be exiting abnormally.
  The log file for this session is at /var/folders/26/hqgjyf0j7192hmjdsz17f3v80000gn/T/sbt2587622650679130928.log
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$1.take(CompletionService.scala:29)
    at sbt.Execute.next$1(Execute.scala:74)
    at sbt.Execute.processAll(Execute.scala:77)
    at sbt.Execute.runKeep(Execute.scala:57)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.run$1(EvaluateTask.scala:109)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.runTask(EvaluateTask.scala:124)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$7.apply(Aggregation.scala:87)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$7.apply(Aggregation.scala:85)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.withStreams(EvaluateTask.scala:87)
    at sbt.Aggregation$.runTasks(Aggregation.scala:85)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyDynamicTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:141)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyDynamicTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:136)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:64)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:64)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Main.scala:121)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Main.scala:121)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:154)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(Main.scala:121)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(Main.scala:121)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(Main.scala:121)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(Main.scala:114)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(Main.scala:103)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(Main.scala:100)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(Main.scala:100)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(Main.scala:83)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(Main.scala:67)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(Main.scala:60)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project needs more memory to be executed (that's what the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` tells you). I have never used the typesafe stack, thus I don't know if it is possible to configure memory parameters directly.

But if you run Linux you can type

```
env JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xss1M -XX:MaxPermSize=512" <command>
```

where command is the command to execute your project (probably it is `sbt`). Of course, you can change the size of the parameters if you need more/less space.